# Not able to plot a function of two variables defined by summation

Tags: plotting, summation

I have the following code:

```
Clear[S, x, y, M]
S[x_, y_, M_] := 
  Sum[a[n]*Sin[n Pi x] Sinh[n Pi (1.5 - y) ], {n, 1, M}] + 
  Sum[b[m] Sin[m Pi x/1.5]*Sinh[m Pi/1.5 y ], {m, 1, M}] + 
  Sum[c[j] Sin[j Pi (1.5 - x)/1.5]*Sinh[j Pi/1.5 y ], {j, 1, M}] + 
  Sum[d[k] Sinh[k Pi x] Sin[k Pi/1.5 y ], {k, 1, M}]

Plot3D[S[x, y, 10], {x, 0, 1.5}, {y, 0, 1.5}]
```

I am not getting a plot from this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please give some explanations. What are `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`?

Answer (score 1):

If I rewrite your function `S` in more reasonable and efficient way while removing the undefined quantities, `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`, I have

```
S[x_, y_, M_] :=
  Sum[
    Sin[i Pi x] Sinh[i Pi (1.5 - y)] + 
    Sin[i Pi x/1.5] Sinh[i Pi/1.5 y] + 
    Sin[i Pi (1.5 - x)/1.5] Sinh[i Pi/1.5 y] + 
    Sinh[i Pi x] Sin[i Pi/1.5 y], 
    {i, 1, M}]
```

and I get the plot

```
Plot3D[S[x, y, 10], {x, 0, 1.5}, {y, 0, 1.5},
  ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image: plot]

Without, definitions for  `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`, I think that's the best I can do for you.